# How do I get id of merged JPA entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a little application where I store entity to DB. I do this in next way:

```
class Entity {
    privete id;
    String somePropertie;
    // getters and setters
}
// In main class
Entity newEntity = new Entity();
newEntity.setSomePropertie("somePropertie");
Entity entity = entityManager.merge(newEntity);
System.out.println("This is id of stored entity:", entity.getId())
```

The didn't write the jpa annotations here. But the entity is stored to database, but the printed id is 0; I using transaction driven by spring, I need this entity for later updates of the entity id.

Comment: If the returned ID is 0, then its ID must really be 0. Have you checked the database? How is the ID generated? You should provide the real code, with the mapping.

Comment: The ID is 503, I'm using hibernate, but entity manager is from spring: **org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean**

Comment: Provide the real code, with the mapping. Show us the table definition and the way the ID generation is configured. Tell us which database you're using.

Answer (score 1):

EntityManager.merge(..) gets an instance and returns an instance that is managed. And in case of transient instances it returns a new instance (does not modify the original)

So your mergeEntity(..) method should return em.merge(entity)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but have you tried with

```
Entity entity = entityManager.merge(newEntity);
System.out.println("This is id of stored entity:", entity.getId())
```

in the same transaction?

Also try setting id to `Long` rather than `long` (or `Integer` rather than `int`; it is not clear from your definition)